# Java encapsulation setters not changing instance variables

Tags: java, encapsulation, setter, instance-variables

My code is made up of 2 classes. (1. Test) (2. Dog)

The purpose of the code is for test to make 3 dogs and using setters set the dogs name and size, then make the 3 dogs bark.

Here is my code.

```
public class Dog {
private int size;

public void bark(){
    System.out.println("Size: " + size);
    if(size > 19) System.out.println("Woof Woof Woof");
    if(size > 9 && size < 20) System.out.println("Bark Bark Bark");
    if(size < 10 && size > 0) System.out.println("Yip Yip Yip");
    if(size == 0) System.out.println("Size Not Set");
}

public void setSize (int s){
    if(size > 0 && size < 60) size = s;
    if(size > 60) { 
        size = 60; 
        System.out.println("Debug: Size sent to large resetting to max.(60)"); 
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Test{
public static void main (String[] args){

//dog size
int s1 = 100;
int s2 = 100;
int s3 = 100;

//create dog and make him bark
Dog d1 = new Dog();
d1.setSize(s1);
d1.bark();

//create dog and make him bark
Dog d2 = new Dog();
d2.setSize(s2);
d2.bark();

//create dog and make him bark
Dog d3 = new Dog();
d3.setSize(s3);
d3.bark();
}}
```

Here is the output

```
Size: 0
Size Not Set
Size: 0
Size Not Set
Size: 0
Size Not Set
```

I think when `Dog` is running `setSize` it is not chaning `size` to the passed argument? If so how do i fix this?

When i change `private int size;` to `private int size = 10;` it works.
However when i change it to `private int size = 0;` it does not.

Why is this?

Comment: why do you check size ?

Comment: change size > 60; to s>60

Answer (score 4):

your setter logic is not correct:

```
 if(size > 0 && size < 60) size = s;
    if(size > 60) { 
        size = 60;
```

by default size is initialise to  zero, so calling the setter is not working because that condition is never checked!

you need to check the parameter **s** instead of the field **size**!

Answer (score 1):

Change your size `setter` to

```
public void setSize (int size){
    if(size > 0 && size < 60) this.size = size;
    if(size > 60) { 
        this.size = 60; 
        System.out.println("Debug: Size sent to large resetting to max.(60)"); 
    }
}
```

It was no point checking the value of `size` as it had not yet been set

Answer (score 0):

change `size > 60`; to `s>60`